# Can Byakugan/Rinnegan eyes be transplanted on non-Byakugan/Rinnegan users?

Tags: naruto

Title says it all. Byakugan, Sharingan and Rinnegan are considered the three great Dojutsus. We see that Sharingan eyes can be transplanted on non-Sharingan users as in the case of Obito's Sharingan being transplanted on Kakashi and Shishui's eyes on Danzo Shimura (albeit deceitfully), is it possible to transplant other Dojutsu eyes on non-Dojutsu users?

Dojutsu are considered *kekkei genkai* i.e. the powers are natural and in-born to members of a particular bloodline. Non-bloodline members can also obtain the powers of kekkei genkai but they have difficulty handling the powers(more chakra is consumed).If we consider dojutsu, Sharingan can be transplanted on both bloodline and non-bloodline members, is it possible for Byakugan and Rinnegan?

[There was a previous question which discussed if Naruto can awaken Sharingan and Rinnegan since he is a reincarnation of some God](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/56706/could-naruto-have-awakened-the-sharingan-or-the-byakugan) where the answers proved he can't. If Naruto's eyes be replaced with Byakugan or Rinnegan eyes (direct transplantation), can he handle the powers? Is such transplantation possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible for Byakugan and Rinnegan?

Yes, it is possible to transplant a [Byakugan](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Byakugan) eye. This has been shown in the series by the shinobi [Ao](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Ao). Unlike Kakashi and his Sharigan, Ao can active and deactived it at will.

> unlike other dōjutsu that have been transplanted, Ao can activate and deactivate his Byakugan at will.

The [Rinnegan](https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Rinnegan) can also be transplanted, as seen with both Nagato and Obito

> If Naruto's eyes be replaced with Byakugan or Rinnegan eyes (direct transplantation), can he handle the powers?

The transplant is theorically possible, since transplants has been shown various times throughout the series. However, given how this is also not shown in the series, whether Naruto can handle the powers or not would be speculation and opinon-based until the writers decide to incorperate this.